# Set focus explicitly to CMFCRibbonEdit

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to create a search box on Ribbon bar of my application.
It should search for given text in a tree control, on hitting Enter button, but without loosing it's focus/selection.
Currently when I am hitting enter it loses it's focus, and makes user to click in that search box again in order to continue.

My search box is a CMFCRibbonEdit control.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing the code you've tried would help.

Comment: I haven't coded for setting focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem, and the solution is a bit painful.  If you look at the source for **CMFCRibbonEdit** you'll see it has a protected member **CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl* m_pWndEdit;**  Internally the ribbon code uses **m_pWndEdit->SetFocus();** to set focus on the edit control. You can derive a class from CMFCRibbonEdit using something like

```
class CMyRibbonEdit : public CMFCRibbonEdit
{
public:
    void SetFocus()
    {
        m_pWndEdit->SetFocus();
    }
};
```

but it has problems.  Notably setting the focus calls the command handler for the edit window, so if you call SetFocus from that function you're liable to hit recursion and a stack fault.

Comment: The recursion can be avoided by setting a flag before `SetFocus` and clearing it afterwards. In the handler, check the flag to do the job or just return.